# Decrypt Text In Dart Which Was Encrypted in Android

Tags: android, encryption, dart

I am trying to decrypt a string in Dart which I have encoded in Android. I have tried everything I can think of using the encrypt package on dart but things don't seem to be working.

Here is the android code:

```
fun String.encrypt(): String {

    fun getByteBuffer(crypt: ByteArray, iv: ByteArray): ByteArray {
        val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 + iv.size + crypt.size)
        byteBuffer.putInt(iv.size)
        byteBuffer.put(iv)
        byteBuffer.put(crypt)
        return byteBuffer.array()
    }

    val key = EncryptionExtension.encryptionKey.toByteArray()
    val iv = ByteArray(12)
    SecureRandom().apply { nextBytes(iv) }
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"), GCMParameterSpec(128, iv))
    return Base64.encodeToString(getByteBuffer(cipher.doFinal(this.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)), iv), Base64.DEFAULT)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter encrypt package does not support AES/GCM. try using supported mode as mentioned in package read me.

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

void main() {
  final plainText = 'hello';
  final key = Key.fromUtf8('this is a key');
  final iv = IV.fromLength(16);

  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));

  final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
  final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);

  print(decrypted); 
  print(encrypted.base64);
```

}

and change 'AES/GCM/NoPadding' with 'AES/CBC/NoPadding' on your java code and the rest which need edit.

Comment: I read that gcm was basically ctrv so I was using that. Do you know of any package that does support gcm? The problem is that my Android code is long standing so I can't change it since there's a lot of data there already.

Comment: there is a package called cipher2.
read this github link : https://github.com/shyandsy/cipher2
I dont know it work or not but it worth trying

Comment: if it does not work deploy a encrypt/decrypt method on java side and call it from flutter using platform channel. also read this article: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: Thank you, my current issue is that when I try to decode from base64 it appears to be incorrect